# C# GetType(string) on Enum returns null

Tags: c#, enums, gettype

I am trying to obtain the type of an `enum` definition from a string of the `enum` name - for example:

```
namespace MySpace
{
    public class MyEnums
    { 
        public enum MyTestEnum { ... }
    }
}

Type enumType = GetType("MyEnums.MyTestEnum")
```

However, every method I have tried returns `null`.  In researching this issue, people have pointed out a number of things to be aware of, so here is what I have tried, without success:

1. Using the fully qualified class name including the namespace - `"MySpace.MyEnums.MyTestEnum"`
2. Adding the assembly name to the string, e.g., `"MySpace.MyEnums.MyTestEnum, MyAssembly"`
3. Iterating through all of the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` assemblies and using `assembly.GetType("MySpace.MyEnums.MyTestEnum")`
4. Getting the assembly object containing the `MyEnums` class and using that:

   ```
   Assembly assembly = typeof(MyEnums).Assembly; 
   Type enumType = assembly.GetType("MySpace.MyEnums.MyTestEnum");
   ```

I can, of course, easily get the type of `"MySpace.MyEnums"`, but not the enums within it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

> I am trying to obtain the type of an enum definition from a string of the enum name

```
Type enumType = Type.GetType("MySpace.MyEnums+MyTestEnum");
```

For future problems, you can use `typeof(MySpace.MyEnums.MyTestEnum).FullName;`
to  get an idea how type names are generated/used.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out - need to use the GetNestedType() method on the MyEnums class type

Comment: And how does this post answer your own question `I am trying to obtain the type of an enum definition from a string of the enum name` ?